# Let $S$ be a regular surface and let $F$ be a diffeomorphism. How can I prove that the image $F(S)$ is a regular surface?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

> Let $S$ be a regular surface and let $F$ be a diffeomorphism. How can I prove that the image $F(S)$ is a regular surface ?

Consider a regular surface $S \subset \mathbb R^3$ and a diffeomorphism $F: \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$.

How can I prove that the image $F(S) \subset \mathbb R^3$ is a regular surface ?

My idea is:

Given $x \in F(S)$, I look at $y = F^{-1}(x) \in S$. By definition there exist open sets $U \in \mathbb R^2$ and $W \in \mathbb R^3$ such that $x \in S \cap W$ and $\sigma: U \rightarrow S \cap W$ a homeomorphism that is smooth (and some more).

I then look at $F(S \cap W) = F(S) \cap F(W)$, but how do I know $F(W)$ is open ? Should I maybe look at the composition of functions ?

How can this be used to prove that the ellipsoid $$\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 \mid \frac {x^2} {a^2} + \frac {y^2} {b^2} + \frac {z^2} {c^2} = 1\}$$ is a regular surface ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea to look at the preimage and compose the charts with the diffeomorphism. To proceed, remember that diffeomorphism is, in particular, a homeomorphism, and so identifies open sets in the domain and the range.

In considering the ellipsoid, is there something similar to an ellipsoid you already know is a regular surface? Can you relate this something to the ellipsoid via a map which is a diffeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: I've been looking independetly on the ellipsoid part. I cannot relate the ellipsoid to anything for which I know a diffeomorphism between them. I've been thinking about a sphere, but then how would the diffeomorphism look ?

Comment: @user111854 What map carries a sphere to an ellipsoid?

Comment: I cannot think of anything simple I've seen previously :/

Comment: How can I verify that the vectors of the composite are linearly independent ?

Comment: $F$ is a diffeomorphism, so its differential is an isomorphism on each tangent space.

Comment: Is there a more elementary way to say that ? I've not read anything about tangent Spaces yet.

Comment: Sorry --- is this for a curves-and-surfaces class? The Jacobian of $F$ is an invertible matrix.

Comment: Just differential-geometry elementary.

Comment: But how can I say that the Jacobian of $F$ is invertible ? I don't know $F$ other than it is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Ahh, I see that $F \circ F^{-1} = i_d$ imply this ! Thanks.